# Wordpress Front End for Custom Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

This is Wordpress Front end Form for categories where people choose categories to submit listing
My Custom Taxonomy is 'location'
but below code shows custom taxonomy of 'listcat' how can i edit it to show 'location' taxonomy?

```
<div class="form_row">

    <div class="label">

        <label for="category"><?php echo CATEGORY; ?><span class="required">*</span></label>

    </div>

    <div class="field">

        <div style="height:100px; width: 290px; overflow-y:scroll; margin-bottom: 15px;">

            <?php

            global $wpdb;

            $taxonomy = CUSTOM_CAT_TYPE;

            $table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;

            $wpcat_id = NULL;

            //Fetch category                          

            $wpcategories = (array) $wpdb->get_results("

                    SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}terms, {$table_prefix}term_taxonomy

                    WHERE {$table_prefix}terms.term_id = {$table_prefix}term_taxonomy.term_id

                    AND {$table_prefix}term_taxonomy.taxonomy ='" . $taxonomy . "' and  {$table_prefix}term_taxonomy.parent=0  ORDER BY {$table_prefix}terms.name ASC");



            $wpcategories = array_values($wpcategories);

            if ($wpcategories) {

                echo "<ul class=\"select_cat\">";

                if ($taxonomy == CUSTOM_CAT_TYPE) {

                    ?>

                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="selectall" id="selectall" class="checkbox" onclick="displaychk_frm();" /></label><?php echo SLT_ALL; ?></li>



                    <?php

                }

                foreach ($wpcategories as $wpcat) {

                    $counter++;

                    $termid = $wpcat->term_id;

                    $name = $wpcat->name;

                    $termprice = $wpcat->term_price;

                    $tparent = $wpcat->parent;

                    ?>

                    <li><label><input class="list_category" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="<?php echo $termid; ?>" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="checkbox" /><?php echo $name; ?></label></li>

                    <?php

                    $args = array(

                        'type' => POST_TYPE,

                        'child_of' => $termid,

                        'parent' => '',

                        'orderby' => 'name',

                        'order' => 'ASC',

                        'hide_empty' => 0,

                        'hierarchical' => 1,

                        'exclude' => '',

                        'include' => '',

                        'number' => '',

                        'taxonomy' => CUSTOM_CAT_TYPE,

                        'pad_counts' => false);

                    $acb_cat = get_categories($args);



                    if ($acb_cat) {

                        echo "<ul class=\"children\">";

                        foreach ($acb_cat as $child_of) {

                            $term = get_term_by('id', $child_of->term_id, CUSTOM_CAT_TYPE);

                            $termid = $term->term_taxonomy_id;

                            $term_tax_id = $term->term_id;

                            $name = $term->name;

                            ?>

                            <li><label><input class="list_category" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="<?php echo $termid; ?>" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="checkbox" /><?php echo $name; ?></label></li>

                            <?php

                            $args = array(

                                'type' => POST_TYPE,

                                'child_of' => $term_tax_id,

                                'parent' => '',

                                'orderby' => 'name',

                                'order' => 'ASC',

                                'hide_empty' => 0,

                                'hierarchical' => 1,

                                'exclude' => '',

                                'include' => '',

                                'number' => '',

                                'taxonomy' => CUSTOM_CAT_TYPE,

                                'pad_counts' => false);

                            $acb_cat = get_categories($args);

                            if ($acb_cat) {

                                echo "<ul class=\"children\">";

                                foreach ($acb_cat as $child_of) {

                                    $term = get_term_by('id', $child_of->term_id, CUSTOM_CAT_TYPE);

                                    $termid = $term->term_taxonomy_id;

                                    $term_tax_id = $term->term_id;

                                    $name = $term->name;

                                    ?>

                                    <li><label><input class="list_category" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="<?php echo $termid; ?>" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="checkbox" /><?php echo $name; ?></label></li>

                                    <?php

                                }

                                echo "</ul>";

                            }

                        }

                        echo "</ul>";

                    }

                }

                echo "</ul>";

            }

            ?>   

        </div>                

    </div>

</div>

<!--End Row-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Find this line

```
$taxonomy = CUSTOM_CAT_TYPE;
```

and replace it with

```
$taxonomy = 'location';
```

May be it helps, but not sure.